# Eclipse "build path" and m2e. Maven --> "Update project configuration" always re-orders my build path

Tags: eclipse, m2eclipse, buildpath

I am developing a CXF web service consumer and I'm forced to use a fairly elderly version of Java (1.6.0_24 on RHEL6).

I have added various Maven dependencies to compensate for older versions of various objects in the Java system libraries.

So, in the build path (in Eclipse) the order matters: It needs to hit the Maven dependencies before it hits the JRE system libs, or else compilation errors occur.

If I right click on my project and select "Maven" --> "Update project configuration" after modifying the POM file etc, m2e seems to re-order the build path libraries so that Maven dependencies come *after* the JRE system libs, which I don't want.

Is there any way of specifying the build path order somewhere (e.g. in the POM etc) so it sticks?

Thanks.

Comment: same question here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7810346/eclipse-m2e-change-order-and-export with tiny hint how to achieve this...